# Does 'throw new Exception' require exit()?

Tags: php, exception

I'm trying to figure out whether the code located after `throw new Exception` in PHP is still executed - I've tried it and it didn't seem to output anything but would like to know for sure.

Comment: I wonder what the point of an Exception is if it doesn't cause a stack-unwind (until the appropriate conditions, e.g. `catch`, stop it from unwinding said stack)...

Comment: _When an exception is thrown, code following the statement will not be executed, and PHP will attempt to find the first matching catch block. If an exception is not caught, a PHP Fatal Error will be issued with an "Uncaught Exception ..." message, unless a handler has been defined with set_exception_handler()._  [From the docs.](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

No, code after throwing an exception is not executed.

In this code example i marked the lines which would be executed (code flow) with numbers:

```
try {
    throw new Exception("caught for demonstration");                    // 1
    // code below an exception inside a try block is never executed
    echo "you won't read this." . PHP_EOL;
} catch (Exception $e) {
    // you may want to react on the Exception here
    echo "exception caught: " . $e->getMessage() . PHP_EOL;             // 2
}    
// execution flow continues here, because Exception above has been caught
echo "yay, lets continue!" . PHP_EOL;                                   // 3
throw new Exception("uncaught for demonstration");                      // 4, end

// execution flow never reaches this point because of the Exception thrown above
// results in "Fatal Error: uncaught Exception ..."
echo "you won't see me, too" . PHP_EOL;
```

See [PHP manual on exceptions](http://php.net/exceptions):

> When an exception is thrown, code following the statement will not be executed, and PHP will attempt to find the first matching catch block. If an exception is not caught, a PHP Fatal Error will be issued with an "Uncaught Exception ..." message, unless a handler has been defined with `set_exception_handler()`.

Answer (score 6):

No, code after the `throw` statement is not executed. Much like `return`.